# PHP: Breaking out of PHP for HTML but return as value instead of print on page?

Tags: php, php4

I am generating a lot of HTML code via PHP, but I need to store it in a variable, not display it immediately. But I want to be able to break out of PHP so my code isnt a giant string.

for example (but actual code will be much larger):

```
<?php
$content = '<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>';
?>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<?php
$content = 
?>
<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
<?php
;
?>
```

But I know this will not return the html as a value it will just print it to the document.

But is there a way to do this tho?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Or a slightly different method is [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php
$content = <<<EOT
<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
EOT;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$var = <<<EOD
my long string
EOD;
echo $var; 
?>
```

(edit done, but one has edit faster than me :))

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should look into a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). It can help you take some of the ugliness out of hardcoding HTML into the PHP file, and can help make the code more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the html in an html file and read that file into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

While still technically a string, you might find the documentation on PHP's heredoc to be an entertaining read:

[heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$content = <<<EOT

<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.